# “Unable to set the Width property of the Range class”

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on automating the construction of a Cost Estimate sheet, sitting on top of the assumptions, rules, policies, etc

All going well until I want to automate setting column widths. Here a short distillation...

```
Dim NumCE As Integer
Dim TotalWidth As Integer

NumCE = 1
Sheets("Cost Estimate").Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = 17  'THIS WORKS

TotalWidth = 17
Sheets("Cost Estimate").Range("B:B").Width = TotalWidth / NumCE 'THIS PROVOKES THE ERROR MESSAGE
Sheets("Cost Estimate").Range("B:B").Width = TotalWidth 'THIS PROVOKES THE ERROR MESSAGE - AS DOES THIS!
```

I'm working with Excel 2016 under the overall O365 bundle and within Windows 10 OS

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `Range("B:B").ColumnWidth`??? In the second part you just use `Width` which is read only.

Answer (score 8):

For those with a similar issue who stumble upon this post, note that it is possible to get the error even when the syntax is correct, if the assigned value is too large.

The unit of `ColumnWidth` is not measured in pixels or centimeters, but instead:

> [is equal to the width of one character in the Normal style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.ColumnWidth).

With standard font settings:

- values larger than 255 will generate the error
- values in the range 94 to 255 throw a warning that the column width exceeds the page width
- values less than 94 will pass

Answer (score 1):

Use `ColumnWidth`:

```
Sub fjsh()
    TotalWidth = 17
    Sheets("Cost Estimate").Range("B:B").ColumnWidth = TotalWidth
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Away from coding mistakes, this error could also be if the worksheet is protected. Hence, unprotecting the sheet will solve this matter.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Or shall I say, Salam (I am a Muslim too :)). Currently, your answer is not really an "answer". Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/

Your content better deserves to be in the comments part but currently, you don't have enough reputation points to comment, but this doesn't justify writing an answer that isn't really an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52697945/19041857) from Egalth has pointed the most applying root cause (especially when you perform a calculation of required width - you might get out of allowed limit).

Here is just a useful workaround - how to set the column width in points (~ pixels) if required. (I didn't find a direct interface with such functionality so far.)

*Note: I'm giving example in python, but for VB it would be quite similar:*

```
col_index = 5 # index of column to set the width as example
width_points = 100 # required width in points (not in characters!), as example
# Note: you can add checks of the input data and values retrieved during processing below
curr_width_points = sheet.Columns(col_index).Width
curr_width_chars = sheet.Columns(col_index).ColumnWidth
width_chars = curr_width_chars * width_points / curr_width_points # this will give float result
if 255 < width_chars: # we are above allowed limit, need correction
    width_chars = 255 # with 255 - just a warning might be generated
sheet.Columns(col_index).ColumnWidth = width_chars
```

The shown workaround uses information about current column width in points and in characters. As smaller was the original column width - as less precise would be the calculation used by the workaround.

Anyway - the usage of characters as width parameter is also a bit strange: there could be different fonts/sizes within same row, so configuring the column width in characters doesn't help a lot. The most precise way would be to set the width in pixels after calculation of cells-width in pixels based on cells-content and font-formats.

Answer (score -1):

' ----
' ----  Format Column A - Record Type
' ----
Sub FormatColumnA()

```
Sheets("Monthly Journal Entry").Activate
Columns("A:A").Select
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = xlGeneral
    .ColumnWidth = 10
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
```

End Sub

This Code works if the spreadsheet is not protected.